# Load a static id from ajax Request by load site

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I made a ajax content Loader after clicking by a tab.
I want to load a static id when I load the site where the ajax tab tool ist.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){

$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
var $this = $(this),
    loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
    targ = $this.attr('data-target');

$.get(loadurl, function(data) {
    $(targ).html(data);
});

$this.tab('show');
return false;

});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Call is:

```
/ajax/call.php?id=
```

i had a static page A and in this static page i have a ajax loader B. the ajax loads content into page A on click Tab Element. I want when i load page A that ajax make a automatic request to B by giving ajax a static id like /ajax/call.php?id=122

Comment: more details please, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understand you well. Try `loadurl = $this.attr('href') + $this.attr('id');` ?